# How do I show a bootstrap tooltip with an SVG object?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, svg, tooltip, d3.js

I'm going crazy trying to understand why I can show tooltips on regular HTML elements, but not on D3-generated SVGs: http://jsfiddle.net/nachocab/eQmYX/5/

What am I doing wrong?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("a").tooltip({
      'placement': 'bottom'
    }); // this works

    $("my_circle").tooltip({
      'placement': 'bottom'
    }); // this does not work
});
```

Comment: jQuery doesn't play nice with SVG. Try https://github.com/shawnbot/d3-bootstrap

Comment: Haven't looked at the d3-bootstrap project yet... If it is possible, you may have to make use of svg's <foreignObject>. http://jsfiddle.net/BCsGc/1/

Comment: @nachocab - Perhaps I'm totally missing something, but... You accepted the answer from lephix. Do you have a working example of this, of bootstrap tooltips being generated AND being visible? First of all, lephix has "d3.tooltip()", but I believe that is wrong: it needs to be "bootstrap.tooltip()". Here's a fork of your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7bNgC/11/ Sure, the tooltip is getting generated, but it is still not visible.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

The problem was that the tooltip that Bootstrap v2.2.2 generates is a `<div>` that was getting inserted inside the `<svg>`, which made the browser not render it.

I ended up using the latest development version of [Bootstrap Tooltip](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tooltips), which adds a new parameter to determine the container of the tooltip. Now I can do:

```
$(".my_circle").tooltip({
    'container': 'body',
    'placement': 'bottom'
}); // this works!
```

**EDIT - One year later**

For the record, I dropped the jQuery requirement and I'm now using the excellent [d3-tip](https://github.com/Caged/d3-tip) by Justin Palmer.

Comment: Obviously `$(".my_circle")`, with the dot.

Comment: What am i doing wrong here.?? It doesnt seem to work.    http://jsfiddle.net/selvaG/eQmYX/39/

Comment: I've updated your jsfiddle - you can attach to all svg circle elements by using $('svg circle').tooltip...  http://jsfiddle.net/eQmYX/41/

Comment: Had the same problem, adding the 'container': 'body' is what did it for me to get the tooltip outside of the SVG.  Using bootstrap 3.

Comment: The Bootstrap Tooltip link is broken, btw.

Answer (score 4):

Use d3-bootstrap library.
This library will provide you alert, popovers, and tooltip functionalities compatible for D3.js
You can add following code to your jsFiddle.

Add this in your head part.

```
<script src="https://github.com/shawnbot/d3-bootstrap/blob/master/d3-bootstrap.js"/>
```

Add this in your code part.

```
d3.selectAll(".my_circle")
    .call( d3.tooltip().placement("right") );
```

Comment: it doesn't seem to work, see mg1075's comment jsfiddle.net/7bNgC/11