# Errors with manual hiding twitter bootstrap tooltips with HTML5 <object> elements

Tags: javascript, html, object, twitter-bootstrap

For my first JavaScript application I am building a widget based designer, and use a variety of widgets based on SVG included in the main HTML body with object tags. I'm trying to associate a bootstrap tooltip when the user clicks on the widget object, however I'm getting strange errors that don't crop up when using tooltips on other non object HTML elements.

As an object tag swallows mouse events it's not possible to trigger a tooltip with a hover and the only combination I can get to work to show the tooltip is the following code (nothing else works, bootstrap complains about ):

```
document.getElementById(widgetName).setAttribute("title", param0);
setTimeout(function () {
     $("#" + widgetName).tooltip("show");
     }, 1);              // attribute needs to be set after the next tick so the DOM is refreshed.
setTimeout(function () { $("#" + widgetName).tooltip("hide"); }, 2000); // 2 sec delay before hiding
```

This code shows the tooltip but errors out with *Unable to get property 'originalTitle' of undefined or null reference* in IE10 after the 2 second timeout to hide the tooltip. I can't use tooltip object options (eg. the delay option) as I get the same error. Same problem in Chrome although Chrome does not report the error (no hiding though).

I'm sure it has something to do with trying to use tooltips on object tags as tooltips work normally otherwise. However I'm fairly new to JavaScript so let me know if I'm doing something dumb, and the bootstrap/Jquery code is too complex for me to trace the error.

Using: HTML5, IE10, latest twitter bootstrap, visual studio 2012 web

Thanks for any help / pointers.

UPDATE: Added code that inserts the object into the DOM

```
    var objWidget = document.createElement("object");
    objWidget.type = "image/svg+xml";
    objWidget.data = "widgets/" + widgetFile + "." + widgetExt      // location of widget
    objWidget.className = "widget"
    var widgetName = "objWidget" + widgetNum;
    targetDiv = "widgetContainer"
    objWidget.id = widgetName;
    document.getElementById(targetDiv).appendChild(objWidget);   // Add to Div
    var objID = document.getElementById(widgetName);
    objID.addEventListener("load", function () {      // access properties once the file is loaded
        var objDoc = objID.contentDocument;
        objDoc.addEventListener("dragstart", drag_start, false);
        objDoc.addEventListener("dragover", drag_over, false)
        objDoc.addEventListener("drop", drop, false)
        objDoc.getElementById("widget").setAttribute("data-widgetName", widgetName);   // set a data attribute on the SVG that points to the parent object as object that created the event isn't recorded in the event.currentTarget
        objID.setAttribute("draggable", "true")
        objID.style.setProperty("position", "absolute");
        objID.style.setProperty("left", objLeft + "px");
        objID.style.setProperty("top", objTop + "px");
        objID.style.setProperty("z-index", widgets[widgetNum].zOrder);
        objDoc.defaultView.loaded(widgetName);         // run widget startup routine only if it isn't a new widget
        objDoc.defaultView.addEventListener("click", widgetClick, false);
        objDoc.defaultView.addEventListener("dblclick", widgetDblClick, false);
    }, false);
```

Comment: your example code don't show the use of `originalTitle`?

Comment: Bass, if I add original title to the attributes (it actually expects data-original-title) I can't even get the 'show' to work (same error).
Any ideas why bootstrap tooltips would cause this problem on object elements?

Comment: i test your code (add the tooltips to the svg tag) see: http://www.bootply.com/64598 FF and chrome don't have a problem so ie10 maybe cause this error? see also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14697232/how-do-i-show-a-bootstrap-tooltip-with-an-svg-object

Comment: Hi Bass, thanks for setting up the bootply. This works in IE10, however my problem is with SVG inserted into the DOM as object elements (from an external SVG file) not as inline SVG.

Comment: could you add some example code of the insertion to the DOM? Maybe your timeout is fired before the creation?

Comment: @Bass, I have updated the original post with the code used to insert into the DOM (I'm still a javascript beginner so feel free to point out errors in the code). I have tried setting the tooltip through a button click as a test to ensure the DOM is loaded with the object and get the same result (error about originalTitle when hiding).

Comment: Thanks. See also https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/issues/8218 maybe that cause your problem. Try to wrap your object in a div and apply the tooltip on that.

Comment: @Bass, I got this to work finally after rebuilding my web site from scratch using a fresh download of bootstrap. Seems I must have had something corrupt (or version problems). So it is working fine with the object elements. Many thanks for your help and pointers, much appreciated!

Comment: @deanbob well done. Does the example in https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/issues/8218 also works in the newest version of bootstrap?

Comment: @Bass, yep, all working now. Shall I reply to the github saying the issue is closed? Thanks again for your help - if you want post a reply to this thread and I'll mark it as an answer for future viewers.

Comment: yes please do. But first see: http://bootply.com/65102. The third tool tip don't show when i apply it on an object-tag (bootstrap v 2.3.2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i test your code (add the tooltips to the svg tag) see: http://bootply.com/64598 FF and chrome don't have a problem

Comment: Yes, I had a problem with versioning of bootstrap I think as I rebuilt my website and its working now. Thanks for the help.