# Sizing of SVG foreignObject element to fit HTML element

Tags: html, svg, d3.js, size

I am making a visualization using the D3 javascript library. I would like to create tooltips  for some of the elements of the visualization and and my client wants them to look like a 'paper snippets/post-its'. Initially I created plain DIV's for the tooltips using some nice CSS tricks to create the desired appearance. (inspired by [this tutorial](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/lets-create-paper-with-css/))

I would like to use encapsulate the tooltips into the SVG foreignObject-element so its better fits to the visualization and I can manipulate them easily. (e.g. zooming/panning) So my question is : how to get the proper size of the DIV, which lies inside the foreignObject-element, so I can set the size of the foreignObject-element accurately ? Especially when using margin/padding/shadow ....

I figured it out by using *.getBoundingClientRect()* but I do not know if this is the best way.

Here is a code-example :

```
var body = d3.select("body");

var svg = body.append("svg");

var tooltipContainer = svg.append("svg:g");

var html = tooltipContainer.append("foreignObject")
var div = html.append("xhtml:div")
    .attr('class', 'paper-tooltip')
    .html("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec eu enim quam.     Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec eu enim quam. Lorem ipsum     dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec eu enim quam. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,     consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec eu enim quam. ");

var bcr = div[0][0].getBoundingClientRect();

html.attr('x', 50)
    .attr('y', 50)
    .attr('width', bcr.width)
    .attr('height', bcr.height);

svg.call(d3.behavior.zoom().on('zoom', redrawOnZoom));

 function redrawOnZoom(){
    tooltipContainer.attr('transform', 'translate(' + d3.event.translate + ')' + ' scale(' +         d3.event.scale + ')');
};
```

Here is a working jsFiddle example : http://jsfiddle.net/jhe8Y/1/

EDIT:

I realized, that for different shadow-box settings the *.getBoundingClientRect()* will not work. i also realized that with my first solution the *.getBoundingClientRect()* returns too-large size, especially on the right size.

So I tried another way by using the jQuerys .outerWidth(true)/.outerHeight(true) and computing the shadow size manually. This seems to work fine, but it feels just terribly to do something like that.

Is there any other way how to get the exact size of a DIV with all it's components ?

Updated jsFiddle is here : http://jsfiddle.net/jhe8Y/3/

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to scale it up and down. There is no real use of it, right? Then you can set both `foreignObject` `height` and `width` to `1`, and via CSS set `foreignObject { overflow: visible; }`.

Answer (score 0):

I've struggled with this before and I've found that the easiest thing to do is just rely on [Bootstrap's Tooltip](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tooltips).

E.g.

```
// title: this is what gets shown as the title in the tooltip
d3.select('svg').attr('title','This is my tooltip title');

// content: this will show up as the content if you go for 
// popovers instead . 
d3.select('svg').attr('data-content','This is some content');

// set the options – read more on the Bootstrap page linked to above
$('svg').popover({
   'trigger':'hover'
   ,'container': 'body'
   ,'placement': 'top'
   ,'white-space': 'nowrap'
   ,'html':'true' // preserve html formatting
});
```

It boils down to, adding  `title` and `data-content` attributes to whatever svg element you're interested in adding tootltips to. Then, set the content equal to whatever you want. So, in your case, the `html` would be

```
<div class='paper-tooltip'>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, ... etc etc.</div>
```

---

Related:

[How do I show a bootstrap tooltip with an SVG object; Question on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14697232/how-do-i-show-a-bootstrap-tooltip-with-an-svg-object)

[Bootstrap Tooltips](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tooltips)

[My super-short blog post on it](http://adilapapaya.wordpress.com/2014/04/11/twitter-bootstrap-tooltips-and-svg/)